# Watson Knowledge Studio is blocked - what port does it use?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

I am able to use Watson Knowledge Studio.  While on client premise, the WKS is inaccessible.

What port must be opened for access?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that 443 port (https) of these two hosts can be accessible from client environment.

- gateway.watsonplatform.net
- idaas.iam.ibm.com